# java -jar payara-micro-4.1.2.181.jar throwing Cannot find javadb client jar file

Tags: java, payara, javadb

I am getting the following exceptions

> running ==>> java -jar payara-micro-4.1.2.181.jar
>   [2019-01-15T20:55:37.913-0800] [] [1;92m[INFO][0m []
>   [[1;94mfish.payara.micro.boot.runtime.PayaraMicroRuntimeBuilder[0m]
>   [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1547614537913]
>   [levelValue: 800] Built Payara Micro Runtime

And also

> [2019-01-15T20:55:43.539-0800] [] [1;92m[INFO][0m [NCLS-CORE-00046]
>   [[1;94mjavax.enterprise.system.core[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=1
>   _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1547614543539] [levelValue: 800] Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available
>   by default.

I am using jdk 1.8.

Comment: i tried to change jdk version to higher & lower, used older payara-micro versions,, but all fail with same reason. end result is it never starts. it has this @ bottom of stacktrace

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 44 more

Answer (score 0):

The javadb client file exception is irrelevant to your actual problem. It is an INFO level message to tell you that it has looked in the default place for the Apache Derby database libraries, but hasn't found them. This default place only applies to Payara Server, not Payara Micro.

The actual problem you're seeing is in your comment. I can see that you are using a version of Java that includes the JPMS (module system). The modularity introduced in Java 9 is not compatible with your version of Payara Micro, so you will need a version of Java no higher than 8.

You may be able to start Payara Micro on Java 9+ by explicitly adding the java.se.ee module, but there was no change in 4.181 to allow Payara Micro to actually run correctly with JPMS, so it would almost certainly break if you tried to deploy any kind of complex app.

---

**TL;DR**: change to use Java 8 because Payara Micro 4.181 will not run on Java 9 or higher. And the javadb message can be ignored.

**Note:** Even though you say you are using Java 1.8, the stack trace proves that you are not. Double check your Java installation and make sure to definitely use Java 8.